# Mac OS Yosemite : How to start mysql and connect Sequel Pro?

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface, osx-yosemite, sequelpro

I have just installed MySQL using the [installation documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-macosx-excerpt/5.5/en/macosx-installation-startupitem.html).

MySQL is installed in the directory /usr/local as indicated in the documentation.

I attempted to start MySQL using the following command on the command line:

```
/Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
```

1. Is it normal that I did not receive a message in the terminal that MySQL has started.
2. Where is the configuration file location (where do I find the root user account)?
3. After running the MySQL start command, I launched Sequel Pro, but I cannot connect to 127.0.0.1. How can I connect to this? Here is a screenshot of what happens when I attempt to connect:
   [image]

I would just like to to start mysql and connect a gui client, what am I missing?

Comment: I don't know why people vote down for the question and does not explain why !

Answer (score 0):

you need to be `root` to start the service.

type `sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is configured to listen to port 3307 when installed on Yosemite. After you verify that effectively you started the service, change the Port parameter on your Sequel Pro access window and try again.